# No output at H bridge during quick power drop

Tags: mosfet, motor, h-bridge

I used a H bridge with PMW control to drive DC motor in two directions. I observed a strange phenomenon that during quick voltage drop, the PWM output at M2 is cutoff, although the T4 gate PWM input is still provided. It seems that the T4(N-MOS) is not switching during that time.

Test condition:

Power voltage changed from 12V to 6V in 5ms; PWM at T4 gate: frequency 20KHz, duration 90%; T1 is always on before T4 gate PWM is off

Actions:

1. when dv/dt increases, the problem disappears, eg. 12V to 6V in 40ms
2. when T4 gate PWM duration decreases to 50%, the problem disappears, but the M2 waveform is a little strange during voltage drop. [image]
3. when the motor is replaced with a resistor, the problem disappears.
4. when 4.7uF capacitor is applied between M1 and M2, the problem disappears. Meanwhile, the Vpk-pk of M2 is much lower than before.

Assumption:
Since problem disappears when a resistor is used instead of motor, it can be concluded that T4 is always switching properly. The output at M2 is "drawn" by other part. It also can be verified by the 50% PWM duration waveform.
The 4.7uF capacitor helps M2 to remain the pulses. How to explain the phenomenon?

@Further verification:
Drain and source of T1 is shorted, PWM at T4 is provided continuously.
Result: Issue still exits, and M2 recovers to normal PWM output after about 36ms automatically.

[image]

[image]

Comment: T4 cannot pull high. You are seeing a failure to pull M2 high. To me, this says : look elsewhere. For example, at T1. If it's NMOS, look at its gate drive - does the collapsing Vbatt affect its high side driver? There's so much you haven't said about the circuit it would be useless to speculate further.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, Brian. The T1 and T2 are P-MOS and T3,T4 are N-MOS. When motor is moving in other direction with T2 and T3 on, the phenomenon is the same. So I just applied T1,T4 for analysis. It is checked that when T1,T4 is working, T2,T3 are off, during Vbat collapsing. The problem now is when PWM driving signal is normally provided to T4(blue), the output at M2 is pulled low at time t. It looks like T4 can't be switched off. Sorry for missing some information!